# Calcular velocidade Km/h latitude e longitude

Tags: php, matemática

Galera se a cada 5 minutos eu percorro 10 quilometro quantos quilômetros por hora estou percorrendo ?

Se alguém puder ajudar ai agradeço segue o código:

```
function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

$lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
$lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
$lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
$lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

$dist = (6371 * acos( cos( $lat1 ) * cos( $lat2 ) * cos( $lon2 - $lon1 ) + sin( $lat1 ) * sin($lat2) ) );
$dist = number_format($dist, 2, '.', '');
return $dist;
}

echo distancia(-4.077559, -63.127536, -4.063721, -63.038268) . " Km<br />";
```

Comment: Se 5 minutos está para 10km quantos quilometros está para 60 minutos resolve a expressão que vai ter o resultado:

    5x = 60 * 10;
    5x = 600;
    x  = 600 / 5 = 120 KM

Regrinha de três simples...

Comment: V é velocidade, S é espaço, t é tempo. Formula geral para movimento uniforme `V=S/t` substituindo  fica `V=10/5`  portanto `V= 2Km/min` calculando o espaço percorrido em uma hora   `S=v*t` portanto    `S=2*60=120km`

Comment: De "cabeça" uma hora tem quantos 5minutos? resposta: 12, portanto é 12*10=120

Comment: A sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente levando em consideração o código apresentado!

Answer (score 0):

Ficou meio vago onde essa velocidade media vai ser usada. Mas como ficou margem de interpretação, imaginei a seguinte situação:

Baseado na afirmação

> A cada 5 minutos eu percorro 10 quilometro quantos quilômetros por hora estou percorrendo

criei uma função que recebe um tempo em minutos e uma distancia em quilometros e retorna a velocidade media. E depois você "iria" querer verificar quanto tempo, indo na velocidade calculada, seria necessário para percorrer a distancia retornada pela função `distancia()`.

Além disso incluo a solução para essa sua outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265060/php-problema-ao-colocar-a-vari%C3%A1vel), que é basicamente criar variaveis para as latitudes e longitudes. Caso não encaixe nas suas necessidades avise nos comentarios.

```
<?php

$latitude_origem = -4.077559;
$longitude_origem = -63.127536;
$latitude_destino = -4.063721;
$longitude_destino = -63.038268;


function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
    $lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
    $lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

    $dist = (6371 * acos( cos( $lat1 ) * cos( $lat2 ) * cos( $lon2 - $lon1 ) + sin( $lat1 ) * sin($lat2) ) );
    $dist = number_format($dist, 2, '.', '');
    return $dist;
}

/**
@param $tempo um numero, representando os minutos
@param $distancia um double representando a distancia percorrida em $tempo 
(distancia em quilometros)

@return double velocidade em quilometros por hora (Km/h)
*/
function converterParaKmHora($tempo, $distancia){
    //60 representa a quantidade de minutos em uma hora
    $velocidade_km_hora = ($distancia * 60) / $tempo;
    return $velocidade_km_hora;
}

$velocidade_media = converterParaKmHora(5, 10);

$distancia_entre_pontos = distancia($latitude_origem, $longitude_origem , $latitude_destino, $longitude_destino);

echo  $distancia_entre_pontos . " Km<br />";
echo  $velocidade_media . " Km/h<br />";
echo  ($distancia_entre_pontos/$velocidade_media) . " horas para completar o percurso<br />";
```

Comment: Amigão @Juve_v Perfeito sua resposta só não estou conseguindo colocar a variável aparece isso Warning: deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given

Comment: Tipo assim $latitude_origem = $latitude_um;

Comment: ai depende de como você inicializa `$latitude_um`, provavelmente está `null` ou com outra coisa que não é um numero.